# How to get current years full months list and previous years full months list in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get current year months list from (Jan-19-Dec-19) and previous Year month list from (Jan-18-Dec-18) in similar format?

**Expected Out:-**

```
 [Jan-18]

    To
 [Dec-18]

 [Jan-19]

    To
 [Dec-19]
```

Can you help me on this.Please

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: Sql Management Studio 2014

Comment: ,, do you've any table?

Comment: yes,I have  the table

Comment: then show us your table structure and sample data  then it would be easy to answer your question - otherwise it's tough to assume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to have the list of the 24 months you mentioned (current and last year) in the desired format, a solution would be:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(month,number,CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())) AS varchar(4)) + '-01-01'),'MMM') + '-' +
       SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + IIF(number<12,-1,0) AS VARCHAR(4)),3,2)
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND number < 24
```

Comment: Thanks very much ,I'm expecting this solution